# Arduino Linux mint: error: ‘digitalPinToInterrupt’

Tags: linux-mint, arduino-ide

I wanted to interrupt a simple squared voltage and I was using a common program:

```
const byte ledPin = 13;
const byte interruptPin = 2;
volatile byte state = LOW;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), blink, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, state);
}

void blink() {
  state = !state;
}
```

But if I want to verify it with the Arduino Software, this is the error:

```
interrupt.ino: In function ‘void setup()’:
interrupt.ino:11:53: error: ‘digitalPinToInterrupt’ was not declared in this scope
```

I already tried adding libraries, which include this command, but I had problems finding them.
I am using Linux mint and the Arduino software version is:

```
arduino:
  Installed: 2:1.0.5+dfsg2-4
  Candidate: 2:1.0.5+dfsg2-4
  Version table:
 *** 2:1.0.5+dfsg2-4 500
```

And I couldn't install the IDE which I downloaded from https://www.arduino.cc
So this is the version of the package manager in Linux mint.

My question now is, does someone know where to find the libary which includes digitalPinToInterrupt().
There is no libary manager in this version of IDE, so perhaps someone knows how to get a newer version of IDE for Linuxmint.
Thank you

Comment: Take a look [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=370167.0)   You can try to just put the pin number without the digitalPinToInterrupt: `attachInterrupt(interruptPin, blink, CHANGE);`, otherwise installing the latest Arduino software seems to solve the problem

Comment: According to [this](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=370167.0) you can just use the pin number without sending it through the macro. However according to [this](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/3929) the macro is defined in `pins_arduino.h`. Anyway in the latest version this should be fixed.

Comment: I can't install the latest Arduino software version and I can't include pins_arduino.h because it is not complete in github: https://github.com/agdl/Arduino/blob/e3351f6fb1717ce167a9c16781cf2c726f3d239e/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/ethernet/pins_arduino.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

The version 1.8.2 for Linux 64bit on https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software is defective. I found an other one on http://www.arduino.org/downloads.
This version also already includes `digitalPinToInterrupt()`.